# Display Errors in Laravel Built in Auth with confirmed field Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel

I'm having problems with this Authentication with confirmed specifically how to display the errors. That says "It is in active". The code works and the user can't login but there is no error. How I'm going to do it?

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Get the needed authorization credentials from the request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    protected function credentials(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only($this->username(), 'password');

        return array_add($credentials, 'active', '1');
    }
```

Comment: Check session flash documentation of laravel, you can something like this return (something)->with ('messages error,  'your custom text error');

Comment: I know about message error but I don't know how to do it in built in auth.

Comment: which view you want return ?

Comment: Do you want a error in login form if user is not activated?

Comment: Yes. That's what I want. Thanks. Now it only returns "These credentials do not match our records."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside **RegistersUsers** trait there is a function

```
protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
{
    if(!$user->active){
        // store msg in session and display to user
        Auth::logout();
    }

}
```

Similarly

in **AuthenticatesUsers** there is a function

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if(!$user->active){
        //store msg in session and display to user
        Auth::logout();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

add on your class of controller

```
use app\User;
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
protected function credentials(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
        $user_active = User::where('username', $request->username)->first();
        if ($user_active->active != 1){
               return 'error';
        }else{

        return array_add($credentials, 'active', '1');
        }
    }
```

You can insert a validation for user that have "active" = 1, if user that is tryng to login and not is actived it return a error. Please try it and let me kknow if for user not actived return error, if it work i will update my question with messagge error "user not actived" in the view.